# Eclipse can't find openJDK after minor update - Best practice?

Tags: eclipse, centos, yum, java

In a CentOS 7 box, I'm using Eclipse [Mars.2 v4.5.2] with OpenJDK 8.

When I upgraded the box ('yum update') the openJDK package had a minor update, from version:

java-1.8.0-openjdk-1:1.8.0.**91-0**.b14.el7_2.x86_64

to version :

java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.**101-3**.b13.el7_2.x86_64

Then, launching Eclipse failed with this error:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin

*Indeed, the folder mentioned above had been deleted by the yum update.*

**The workaround** I came up with was to launch Eclipse using the -vm flag pointing to the latest openJDK version 8.0.101.

```
/home/olivier/eclipse/cpp-mars/eclipse/eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin
```

**What is the best practice here?** (I'm new to CentOS & openJDK : didn't have that kind of problems with Fedora and Sun/Oracle-JDK).

Comment: Is there a -vm entry pointing to the old location in the eclipse.ini (in the Eclipse install directory)?

Comment: Thanks - yes, eclipse.ini includes a -vm flag pointing to the old location. So, another workaround would be to modify that file, with either the new location, or to use '/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk' a link that seems to point to the latest version folder. Is it best practice?

Comment: I run on a Mac so I can't really say about Linux. I never need an entry in the eclipse.ini